# making GridLayout vertical in Java

Tags: java, vertical-alignment

I'm using `GridLayout` and here is what I want the grid to look like:

```
1  9  
2  10  
3  11  
4  12  
5  13  
6  14  
7  15  
8  16
```

According to this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html it is a matter of `ComponentOrientation`.

`ComponentOrientation` is itself a class that can be passed into the `setComponentOrientation` method of the `Container` class but seems to have no constructor and no way of changing its fields.

Comment: According to the JavaDoc orientation is mainly used for locale specifics so you can't easily create an instance yourself. Do you always want to have 2 columns (or 8 rows) or could there be more if space is available?

Comment: Having a look at the JDK 8 sources GridLayout only seems to distinguish between ltr and rtl orientation so it can'd do vertical layout by itself. You should be able to change the order of components manually though, i.e. add them in the order 1, 9, 2, 10 etc.

Comment: I'm making a dynamic display of labels and the ones in the left column don't change but the ones in the right column do and I use a loop to do it.  I can use two panels with single columns of 8 but I'm kinda surprised at the lack of simple functionality in this case.  It's weird that I'd have to be mongolian or something in order to get that to work.. lol!

Comment: Well, the built-in layout managers aren't the best of breed ;) From my experience a lot of developers use a third party library like MigLayout.

Comment: I'll check it out.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @LukeMartin, `It's weird that I'd have to be mongolian or something in order to get that to work.` Or you use a different layout manager instead of trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Each layout is designed to do something specific. The simpler the layout manager the simpler the layout. The more complex the layout manager the more flexible it is. You could use a `GridBagLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this pretty easily by extending the built-in `GridLayout` and overwriting a single method. I've commented the two lines that are actually different from the parent class implementation. The remaining comments are part of the original class.

```
public class VerticalGridLayout
    extends GridLayout
{

  /**
   * Creates a grid layout with a default of one column per component, in a single row.
   */
  public VerticalGridLayout()
  {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the
   * layout are given equal size.
   * <p>
   * One, but not both, of <code>rows</code> and <code>cols</code> can be zero, which means that any
   * number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.
   * 
   * @param rows the rows, with the value zero meaning any number of rows.
   * @param cols the columns, with the value zero meaning any number of columns.
   */
  public VerticalGridLayout( int rows, int cols )
  {
    super( rows, cols );
  }

  /**
   * Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the
   * layout are given equal size.
   * <p>
   * In addition, the horizontal and vertical gaps are set to the specified values. Horizontal gaps
   * are placed between each of the columns. Vertical gaps are placed between each of the rows.
   * <p>
   * One, but not both, of <code>rows</code> and <code>cols</code> can be zero, which means that any
   * number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.
   * <p>
   * All <code>GridLayout</code> constructors defer to this one.
   * 
   * @param rows the rows, with the value zero meaning any number of rows
   * @param cols the columns, with the value zero meaning any number of columns
   * @param hgap the horizontal gap
   * @param vgap the vertical gap
   * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the value of both <code>rows</code> and
   *              <code>cols</code> is set to zero
   */
  public VerticalGridLayout( int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap )
  {
    super( rows, cols, hgap, vgap );
  }

  @Override
  public void layoutContainer( Container parent )
  {
    synchronized ( parent.getTreeLock() )
    {
      Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
      int ncomponents = parent.getComponentCount();
      int nrows = getRows();
      int ncols = getColumns();
      boolean ltr = parent.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight();

      if ( ncomponents == 0 )
      {
        return;
      }
      if ( nrows > 0 )
      {
        ncols = (ncomponents + nrows - 1) / nrows;
      }
      else
      {
        nrows = (ncomponents + ncols - 1) / ncols;
      }
      // 4370316. To position components in the center we should:
      // 1. get an amount of extra space within Container
      // 2. incorporate half of that value to the left/top position
      // Note that we use trancating division for widthOnComponent
      // The reminder goes to extraWidthAvailable
      int totalGapsWidth = (ncols - 1) * getHgap();
      int widthWOInsets = parent.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
      int widthOnComponent = (widthWOInsets - totalGapsWidth) / ncols;
      int extraWidthAvailable = (widthWOInsets - (widthOnComponent * ncols + totalGapsWidth)) / 2;

      int totalGapsHeight = (nrows - 1) * getVgap();
      int heightWOInsets = parent.getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
      int heightOnComponent = (heightWOInsets - totalGapsHeight) / nrows;
      int extraHeightAvailable = (heightWOInsets - (heightOnComponent * nrows + totalGapsHeight)) / 2;
      if ( ltr )
      {

        for ( int c = 0, x = insets.left + extraWidthAvailable; c < ncols; c++, x += widthOnComponent
            + getHgap() )
        {
          for ( int r = 0, y = insets.top + extraHeightAvailable; r < nrows; r++, y += heightOnComponent
              + getVgap() )
          {

            int i = c * nrows + r; // In the horizontal version, this is: r * ncols + c
            if ( i < ncomponents )
            {
              parent.getComponent( i ).setBounds( x, y, widthOnComponent, heightOnComponent );
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        for ( int c = 0, x = (parent.getWidth() - insets.right - widthOnComponent)
            - extraWidthAvailable; c < ncols; c++, x -= widthOnComponent + getHgap() )
        {
          for ( int r = 0, y = insets.top + extraHeightAvailable; r < nrows; r++, y += heightOnComponent
              + getVgap() )
          {

            int i = c * nrows + r; // In the horizontal version, this is: r * ncols + c
            if ( i < ncomponents )
            {
              parent.getComponent( i ).setBounds( x, y, widthOnComponent, heightOnComponent );
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```